# LG monitor is detected but doesn't function

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics, hdmi

I just bought a new LG monitor to use as a second monitor with my HP laptop (Intel Integrated graphics) running Ubuntu. In my `Settings > Display` I can see my monitor detected in the GUI but on the monitor itself it says `check your HDMI connection`.

I searched a lot, and found LG has Dual Monitor software, but it is not provided for Ubuntu. I tried to use `xrandr` tool but it did not help.

So far on my another Laptop having ubuntu and VGA port its working over there so the problem is with my `HDMI` driver. I have looked for intel drivers on this but don't know will it solve my problem or not.

`xrandr --verbose`

```
eDP1 connected primary 1280x720+0+0 (0xe9) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 165mm
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  3934484
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      1 0 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0030e4540300000000
        00160104901d11780afc359658578e29
        1f505400000001010101010101010101
        0101010101013e1c56a0500016302428
        350025a510000019d41256a050001630
        2428350025a510000019000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000002
        000c3dff0a3c64121222640000000062
    BACKLIGHT: 707 
        range: (0, 937)
    Backlight: 707 
        range: (0, 937)
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
  1366x768 (0x47) 72.300MHz -HSync -VSync +preferred
        h: width  1366 start 1402 end 1442 total 1526 skew    0 clock  47.38KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  776 total  790           clock  59.97Hz
  1366x768 (0xf6) 48.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1366 start 1402 end 1442 total 1526 skew    0 clock  31.59KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  776 total  790           clock  39.98Hz
  1360x768 (0xe7) 84.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.80Hz
  1360x768 (0xe8) 72.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1408 end 1440 total 1520 skew    0 clock  47.37KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock  59.96Hz
  1280x720 (0xe9) 74.480MHz -HSync +VSync *current
        h: width  1280 start 1336 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock  44.76KHz
        v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  746           clock  60.00Hz
  1024x768 (0xea) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  1024x576 (0xeb) 46.995MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1064 end 1168 total 1312 skew    0 clock  35.82KHz
        v: height  576 start  577 end  580 total  597           clock  60.00Hz
  960x540 (0xec) 40.784MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   960 start  992 end 1088 total 1216 skew    0 clock  33.54KHz
        v: height  540 start  541 end  544 total  559           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0xed) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0xee) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  864x486 (0xef) 32.901MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   864 start  888 end  976 total 1088 skew    0 clock  30.24KHz
        v: height  486 start  487 end  490 total  504           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0xf0) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x405 (0xf1) 22.176MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  728 end  800 total  880 skew    0 clock  25.20KHz
        v: height  405 start  406 end  409 total  420           clock  60.00Hz
  680x384 (0xf2) 19.677MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   680 start  688 end  752 total  824 skew    0 clock  23.88KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  388 total  398           clock  60.00Hz
  640x360 (0xf3) 17.187MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  640 end  704 total  768 skew    0 clock  22.38KHz
        v: height  360 start  361 end  364 total  373           clock  60.00Hz
HDMI1 connected 1280x720+1280+0 (0xff) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 440mm x 250mm
    Identifier: 0x44
    Timestamp:  3934484
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      1 0 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff001e6dc75a85890200
        08190103802c1978ea3135a5554ea126
        0c5054a76a80714f81c0a9c0810095c0
        010101010101302a40c8608464301850
        1300b8fa1000001e000000fd00384b1e
        530f000a202020202020000000fc004c
        4720484420504c55530a2020000000ff
        000a2020202020202020202020200190
        02031df14a8404030112121313131323
        0907078301000065030c001000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00011d007251d01e206e285500b8fa10
        00001e8c0ad08a20e02d10103e9600b8
        fa100000180000000000000000000000
        000000000000000000000000000000c0
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
  1600x900 (0xfb) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync +preferred
        h: width  1600 start 1624 end 1704 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1440x810 (0xfc) 95.004MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1512 end 1664 total 1888 skew    0 clock  50.32KHz
        v: height  810 start  811 end  814 total  839           clock  59.98Hz
  1280x800 (0xfd) 71.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.91Hz
  1152x864 (0xfe) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1280x720 (0xff) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync *current
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x100) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  50.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x101) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
  1024x768 (0x102) 78.800MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.06KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.08Hz
  1024x768 (0xea) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  832x624 (0x103) 57.284MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   832 start  864 end  928 total 1152 skew    0 clock  49.73KHz
        v: height  624 start  625 end  628 total  667           clock  74.55Hz
  800x600 (0x104) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0xed) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0xee) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  720x576 (0x105) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
        v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
  720x480 (0x106) 27.027MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x480 (0x107) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0x108) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x109) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0xf0) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x10a) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x198) 172.800MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2040 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.08KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1081 end 1084 total 1118           clock  60.00Hz
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x45
    Timestamp:  3934484
    Subpixel:   no subpixels
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter:
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux nikhil-HP-Pavilion-13-Notebook-PC 4.2.0-25-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 12:31:50 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Only thing coming on screen is Please check your connection .

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include more details, like which specific Ubuntu release and kernel are you using? Have you looked for drivers online? Which specific model is your monitor?

Comment: Updated @cat please check

Comment: Well, the output you posted seems to say Ubuntu knows a bit about the device but can't communicate with it. My guess would be missing drivers, I'll take a look.

Comment: Can you add the output of `uname -a` and your Ubuntu version (15.10, perhaps?)

Comment: Ok I get that - https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads - this links suggests   driver linux kernel with HDMI support should I install that?

Comment: @cat `uname -a` output updated and yes version 15.10

Comment: Yes, install that driver and try running `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` because your kernel is a patch or two behind latest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34670/discussion-between-nikhil-parmar-and-cat).

Comment: Hey @cat I did both the things still nothing working

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to install a second monitor to my desktop via HDMI. In the boot process-the HDMI-port died. I fixed this by disabling the X.Org X server Nouveau display driver and to install and select the NVIDIA binary driver 340.96 in the Ubuntu Software & Updates -> Extra drivers menu.

Now I got a dual screen configuration.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! Thank you for sharing your knowledge, However, doing a quick google search would reveal that the laptop has AMD graphics. I down voted your answer for that reason.

Comment: If you have read the description I have Intel graphics card